# json.net DeserializeObject

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have following code:

```
string code = client.DownloadString("http://oddsportal.com/feed/prematch/1-1-hSpbs4Cd-1-2.dat");
DataSet data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(code.Substring(3, code.Length - 6));
textBox1.Text += "1";
```

But it stops on the second line like if there was return - it doesn't write 1 in the textbox.
What am I doing wrong?

Here it is rewritten with structure: http://pastebin.com/xZAhjU8w
Thanks.

EDIT: A used a try-catch and its exception is:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Additional text found in JSON string after finishing deserializing object.
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent) in c:\Temp\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 177
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) in c:\Temp\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonSerializer.cs:line 711
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) in c:\Temp\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonSerializer.cs:line 663
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings) in c:\Temp\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonConvert.cs:line 797
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings) in c:\Temp\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonConvert.cs:line 757
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value) in c:\Temp\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonConvert.cs:line 694
>      at oddsreader.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\zuz\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\oddsreader\oddsreader\Form1.cs:line 692

When I tried some online json validators, they returned the string was valid. What could be wrong with it?

EDIT2: I might have been completely wrong. So I will ask a simpler quastion. How could I do a foreach of "odds" array and then foreach of its subarrays? The path to odds is: ["d"]["oddsdata"]["back"]["E-1-2-0-0-0"]["odds"]. I haven't found an example code with mode than 2 level arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue isn't with the string, it's with the cast to 'DataSet'. This works fine for me :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    string code = client.DownloadString("http://oddsportal.com/feed/prematch/1-1-hSpbs4Cd-1-2.dat");
    client.Dispose();

    code = code.Replace("-|-", string.Empty);

    JObject json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(code);

    int one = (int)json["d"]["bt"];

    Debug.Assert(one == 1);
}
```

Comment: This is good. Thank you. But now I would need something like `foreach(subarray in json["d"]["oddsdata"]["back"]["E-1-2-0-0-0"])`, how could I do it?

Comment: @LukAss741 You can do this to loop through all the key/values in a child JObject `foreach (JProperty prop in ((JObject)json["d"]["oddsdata"]["back"]["E-1-2-0-0-0"]).Properties()) { Console.WriteLine(string.Format("obj[{0}] = {1}", prop.Name, prop.Value)); }`

but as you can see, with such a poorly formatted JSON it's going to be a PITA

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `JsonConvert` could not execute `DeserializeObject` on your parameter that you passed in.

That is to say `(3, code.Length - 6)` probably does not give you a valid json string, hence JsonConvert cannot convert it.

An exception was probably thrown but you did not catch it, hence, it exhibited the "return" like behavior.

Comment: What do you mean by parameter?

The source is written like -|-{json}-|-, I don't know why. So That substring was used to trim it. Or could this somehow harm the json string?

Comment: Oh, so there's a string `-|-{json}-|-` appended to the front of the json string that is in the pastebin [link](http://pastebin.com/xZAhjU8w)?

Comment: I posted on pastebin its structured code to make it human readable. Original has "-|-" at the begining and end.

Comment: is your DataSet object corresponding to the json string format?

Comment: I don't get what you mean. I don't have too much experience with json and this is the first time I am trying to work with it in c#.
If I had in example tis code:
`{
  "s": 1,
  "d": {
    "bt": 1,
    "sc": 2
  }
}`
Then I would like to acces it like: variable["d"]["bt"]; which would be equal 1. Is this way to approach it even correct?